# Fetch request CoreData from relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

This is the situation, I have two entities in CoreData.

- Question (Chapter:int, Answers:array)
- Answer (Date, Correct:bool)

And this is how they are related:

- The question entity has the chapter where it belongs and a history of answers to that question (that's a relationship).
- The answer entity knows when the question was answered and wether it was correct or not.
- One question has many answers.

The final result I want is something like this...

```
Fetch questions WHERE chapter = <some> and (LAST) answer.correct = YES
```

I'm kind of new with core data and right now I'm doing it with many steps but I wanted to know if I can achieve this with only one NSFetchedResultsController without filtering arrays.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What does `(LAST)` mean in your question? Most recent? Last according to some unspecified sorting? Something else?

Comment: Hi Tom! Yes, it would be the most recent... I mean, if a question has been answered 10 times, I would only care wether the most recent answer was correctly answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little convoluted, but I think the following will get what you want:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chapter like %@ AND (SUBQUERY(answer, $t, $t.correct == YES).date.@max = SUBQUERY(answer, $t, $t.correct IN {YES, NO}).date.@max)"];
```

This checks whether the maximum date for correct answers is equal to the maximum date for all answers.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I think this is returning the last correct answer, but it helps me A LOT, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this predicate. May work for you.

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chapter = '%@' AND answer[LAST].correct=TRUE",chapterName];
```

Comment: Hi Pradip, I tried your solution but it crashed... the closer thing that worked was... filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"chapter = %@ AND ANY answers.isCorrect = YES", self.chapter];

Comment: It says " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression answers[LAST].isCorrect' "